# How to define List<Map<Integer, Set<String>>> property in openapi-generator?

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, hashset, openapi-generator

I define OpenAPI 3.0 documents and use openapi-generator-cli-3.3.4.jar to generate Java code (DTO). 
But I can't solve this case: `List<Map<Integer, Set<String>>>`.

1. In `Map<Integer, String>` issue:

   - As I know I can use [schema object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#schema-object): 
     ***additionalProperties*** define map type.
   - OpenAPI Specification ***additionalProperties***: Value can be boolean or object. Inline or referenced schema MUST be of a Schema Object and not a standard JSON Schema.
   - According above, I can't set Map key to an integer, right? Have any suggestions on this issue?
2. In `set<String>` or `set<List<String>>` issue: I have to try some effort:

***Testing1***: set "uniqueItems": true

```
 {
    "openapi": "3.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "Dr.First Schema",
        "license": {
            "name": "MIT"
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Question": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "test": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items":{
                            "type":"string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Generate Java DTO***: not Set is List

```java
     /**
   * Get test
   * @return test
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public List<String> getTest() {
    return test;
  }

  public void setTest(List<String> test) {
    this.test = test;
  }
```

***Testing2***: edit the properties test type to Set

```
    "test": {
       "type": "Set"       
    }
```

***Warn***

```
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown type found in the schema: Set
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown type found in the schema: Set
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown type found in the schema: Set
```

***Generate Java DTO***: Have syntax error

```java
   /**
   * Get test
   * @return test
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public java.util.* getTest() {
    return test;
  }

  public void setTest(java.util.* test) {
    this.test = test;
  }
```

***Testing3***: edit the properties test type to set

```
    "test": {
       "type": "set"       
    }
```

***Warn***

```
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown type found in the schema: set
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown type found in the schema: set
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Unknown type found in the schema: set
```

***Generate Java DTO***: Have java Set type but no idea to setting generic

```java
      /**
   * Get test
   * @return test
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "")
  public Set getTest() {
    return test;
  }
  public void setTest(Set test) {
    this.test = test;
  }
```

- Have any suggestions to fix `Map<Integer, String>` and java Set generic issue in openapi-generator?

Comment: Hi Eddie, were you able to find a fix to your issue?

Answer (score 1):

For openapi version 3.0.3 this example of Java generic set works

yaml definition:

```
mapOfSets:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: setOfStrings
```

maven pom.xml configuration for openapi-generator-maven-plugin:

```
<typeMappings>
  <typeMapping>setOfStrings=Set&lt;String&gt;</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>

<importMappings>
  <importMapping>Set&lt;String&gt;=java.util.Set</importMapping>
</importMappings>
```

Generated Java code:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> mapOfSets = null;
```

Here **setOfStrings** is a custom openapi type that has custom mappings defined in pom.xml and will generate Set<String> Java type.

Comment: "No enum constant org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.models.media.Schema.SchemaType.SETOFSTRINGS" with openapi-generator-maven-plugin 5.4.0