# Specify a Set in OpenAPI

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am using OpenAPI / Swagger to specify my API.

One thing that I could not find out is how to specify a Set.

I am using https://editor.swagger.io/ and I typed in the whole API. For a property that I want to specify as Set I wrote the following:

```
   myProperty:
      uniqueItems: true
      type: array
      description: some description
      items:
        type: string
```

I would have guessed that *uniqueItems* does the trick and a Set is generated, but this is not the case. Instead the following code is generated:

```
@JsonProperty("myProperty")
private List<String> myProperty = null;
```

Is there a way to generate something like

```
@JsonProperty("myProperty")
private Set<String> myProperty = null;
```

instead?

I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899939/how-to-define-listmapinteger-setstring-property-in-openapi-generator) in SO, but this requires some configuration in a pom.xml. However, the online editor that I am using gives me only the option to generate code for different platforms but does not accept a pom file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenAPI (version 3) supports the following data types:

- string
- number
- integer
- boolean
- array
- object

There is **no support for set data type** in OpenAPI v3. The closest data type is an array with property *uniqueItems* set to true (as you've suggested). But it's still an array with a constraint on the uniqueness of its items, not a set.

So, your request cannot be resolved on the OpenAPI level.

However, there might be an option on the code generator level, and you would need to address the issue to the code generator of your choice.

Comment: I used https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin which allows to specify in the pom file that Sets should be generated.

Comment: @FlorianS. Please, can you share the configuration of the plugin generator ?